# Yellow fade effect on internal link?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a Web site for a restaurant, and as the menu page is somewhat expansive (I am putting the full menu on the site since it is not changed very often), I added some links at the top that jump to specific sections. Even so, the sections near the bottom are somewhat short, and it can be tricky to tell which one you actually jumped to. Setting a :target selector for the headings works, but I don't like the fact that whatever effect I use to distinguish the header never actually goes away.

Is it possible to use jQuery to apply a "yellow fade" effect to an element when it is targeted by an internal link, so that you can tell where you jumped but it doesn't stay around and clutter the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way i do it below includes using the jQuery-ui library, specifically `$("#something").effect("highlight", "slow");`

this will result in a brief pulse of color on whatever was selected by jQuery.  For your solution, you would need pulse the Anchor's header element briefly after clicking on the table of contents.

```
<a href="#someTarget" class="tableOfContents">good food</a>
....html

<a id="someTarget">Good Food</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"/>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(event){
  $(".tableOfContents").click(function(event){
     $($(this).attr("href")).effect("highlight", "slow");
   });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: @LeafStorm you don't need all of the jQuery-ui styling, just the effect function to animate Colors.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. It was a bit of a pain finding the effects core, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why you'd complicate things by handing this off to JavaScript; admittedly it allows for consistent cross-browser support, but most browsers ([with the obvious exception of IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3atarget#section_4)) should be okay with the [`:target` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo), which allows for a pure CSS approach:

#### html:

```
<a href="#link">Go to text</a>

<div id="link">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, and so forth.</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
div {
    display: none;
}

div:target {
    display: block;
    background: #fff url(path/to/animated.gif) 0 0 repeat;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mZtZ5/).

Comment: 1. Considering that the restaurant's owner uses IE, cross-browser support is pretty important. 2. I don't like using GIFs.

Comment: @LeafStorm: well, fair enough on the cross-browser requirements (although JS/jQuery could've aided that in this situation, too), but you "don't like using gifs"? That's fine, and obviously you're entitled to your preferences, but it seems unwise to throw away an entire file-format. May I ask *why* you "don't like gifs"?

Comment: I'd love to only do this in css.  The fiddle demo for the gif example does not support multiple clicks in Chrome atm.  my Css is behind my JS, and I try to remedy that whenever I can.

Comment: Part of it is that I don't actually know how to make animated GIFs. :-) Also, animated GIFs kind of remind me of the Dark Ages of the Internet. I guess that that's not a very good reason though.